# C static scope variable undefined

Tags: c, scope

My goal is to add (without modifying any of the existing code) a function `retrieve()` which returns the current value of the counter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void increment(void){
    static unsigned int counter = 0;

    counter++;

    printf("%d\n", counter);

}

int main(void){

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        increment();
    }
    
    printf("counter = %d\n", retrieve()); 

    return 0;
}
```

However, everything I try is running into a scope issue. Namely that `counter` has not yet been instantiated yet so the compiler considers it to be an undefined name. I've tried adding a function

```
int retrieve(void){

    return counter;
}
```

between `increment` and `main` and also within both `increment` and `main` themselves. My understanding of the `static` keyword is that once the variable is instantiated it will persist beyond the block it is defined in for the length of the program execution. So I think the issue I'm running into is that the variable is not yet instantiated. Any help would be great.

Comment: It may have static storage duration, but it is only visible within `increment` (block scope) - you cannot access it in any other function

Comment: So I would have to define my function within `increment` then to get things working?

Comment: You cannot define functions inside other functions in C. You most likely want to have `counter` at file scope instead

Comment: To be clear, it is not possible to do this without editing the pre-existing code?

Comment: Yes, you need to make `counter` global.

Comment: Yes; you must modify the existing code.  You also can't reset the counter to zero, any more than you can retrieve it.  Variables that are defined as `static` in a function are useful, but also have limitations, and you're just discovering the limitations.

Comment: @RhythmInk Nope, it's not possible

Comment: Yes @Rhythmlnk it's not possible without editing the existing code. You could return a pointer to the static variable, but then you modify the existing code (changing the return from `void` to `unsigned int *`).

Comment: Your understanding of static is correct, but you missed the scope. If you declare a variable in a function, the scope is also limited to the function. In your case, you want to have a static variable that is in scope of your translation unit (c file). So you need to move the declaration of the static variable outside the function, then you can access it from all functions within the *.c file.

Comment: @RhythmInk, I deleted my comment because it essentially duplicates others I upvoted, but that's essentially it, like it is you can't access it, so you can't retrieve its value. So for sure it's meant to be altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope and lifetime are two different things, and they're *partly* independent.

Scope is the region of program text in which an identifier is visible.

Lifetime (or storage duration) is the duration during program execution in which an object exists.

The object named `counter`, because it's defined with `static`, has *static storage duration*, which means that it exists during the entire execution of the program. But the identifier `counter` has *block scope*, which means that the name is visible only from its declaration to the `}` that terminates the innermost block in which it's declared. (In this case, that block happens to be the outermost block of a function definition.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to move counter into global scope

```
#include <stdio.h>
static unsigned int counter = 0; <<<=========
void increment(void){
   

    counter++;

    printf("%d\n", counter);

}
int retrieve(void){

    return counter;
}
int main(void){

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        increment();
    }
    
    printf("counter = %d\n", retrieve()); 

    return 0;
}
```

accepted best practice is to indicate in the name that its global

```
 unsigned int COUNTER = 0;
```

or

```
 unsigned int g_counter = 0;
```

Comment: The OP's constraint of not modifying the existing code does not permit a general solution.  So perhaps a minimal code modification *could* be acceptable.  The `counter` does not need global scope:  it just needs to be accessible to the (additional) modify function.

Comment: Minor comment to your proposal. As long as the variable is only used within this file, it’s good practice to declare it static to not export the symbol when its actually not needed.

Comment: My experience is that all-caps names are used for macros and constants.  I've never seen a coding style that would use this for variables, global or otherwise.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have been in rust land, its all caps there